# Angular - adding styles based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm writing my first Angular app - wasn't sure how best to describe this so excuse me if its already been answered.

I'm using `ng-repeat` to display some JSON data:

```
<ul class="no-bullet" ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <li>{{person.name}}
     <div class="graphBar"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

That div I have with class `graphBar` contains some CSS in which I'm setting

```
.graphBar {
background: linear-gradient(to right,
          $Colour1 0%, $Colour1 33%,
          $Colour2 33%, $Colour2 55%,
          $Colour3 55%, $Colour3 80%,
          $Colour4 80%, $Colour4 100%);
}
```

What i need advice on is how do I send data from `{{person.options}}` to some function so that I can process it in order to the percentages for the CSS and then to that div?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Checkout this, if it looks like that what you want (at least visually): https://plnkr.co/edit/B0OGpNhpsKTmG3x9vLvy?p=preview

Comment: What do you want to change dynamically? Percentage, colors or both?

Comment: Both - I think what I'm going to have to do is get this processed server side, so when the data comes in i just place it in. Can't think of any other way

Comment: Infact - could i create a directive - say called `graphBar` then pass into that to do the smart processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here (Plunker)](https://plnkr.co/edit/eDVX53cDyftd4SlspffT?p=preview) is my solution.

Posible data format:

```
`{ name:'John', colors: {red:33, yellow: 15, green: 10, blue: 20}}`
```

Angular app:

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyAppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.styleBuilder = function (colors){
        var raw = ['linear-gradient(to right, ']
        var pointer = 0
        for (var key in colors){
            raw.push(key+ ' ' + pointer + '%,  ' + key + ' ' + (colors[key]+pointer) + '%, ')
            pointer += colors[key];
        }
        if(pointer<100){ //here we are checking if percentages add up to 100%
            raw.push('#D8E0E3' + ' ' + pointer + '%,  ' + '#D8E0E3' + ' ' + 100 + '%')
        }
        raw.push(')')
        return raw.join('')
    }

    //example data (use $http to get data from backend)
    $scope.persons = [
        { name:'John',
            colors: {red:33, yellow: 15, green: 10, blue: 20}
        }, 
        {name:'Mary',
            colors: {red:10, yellow: 25}
        }, 
        {name: 'Piter',
            colors: {green: 70, blue: 20}
        }
    ]

})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="no-bullet" ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <li>{{person.name}}
       <div class="graphBar" ng-style="{'background': styleBuilder(person.colors)}"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eDVX53cDyftd4SlspffT?p=preview) for more details.

End result:

[image]

Comment: Mate you're a legend! Thats exactly what I needed to understand - that section `styleBuilder` and using it within the $scope perfect.
Very much appreciated.

Comment: Sure! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like `ng-style`.

Something like:

```
 <div ng-style="{background: 'linear-gradient(to right, person.options.to, person.options.right)'}"></div>
```

Comment: Ok - but how would I pass it to a function first as the data I get from `person.options` will be in an array like `["classa : 5","classb : 3","classc : 5"]` so i need to 'recreate' that into an appropiate string?

Comment: Also - I need to get the variables `$Colour1` etc whcih are SASS varibales. Can i update the css from code?